# How to connect bluetooth on primeos?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi4

After installing Primeo on the Raspberry Pi, I connected the Bluetooth device (usb).

However, nothing appears in the list of Bluetooth devices, only infinite loading repeats, and nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I tried changing the Bluetooth device, but the symptoms are the same.

All I wanted was a list of devices that could connect via Bluetooth.

Please check my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USoXW.jpg).